# French “Collocation in Use” book

Tags: grammaire, choix-de-mot, ressources

I learned French words by the list 5000 Most Common French Words and I found that it has many synonyms that sometimes I've mistaken in using them.

In English we have the series English Collocation in Use and it's quite helpful. I wonder is there any similar book for French?

Answer (score 4):

[*Cooccurrence*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cooccurrence) is the word you'd be looking for to translate *collocation*.

I haven't been a huge fan of this kind of book, so I won't be a very good reference in the comparative values of the available offers, but I've seen them around for sure.

Here is a point to start from with two such books for you to investigate:

> • [*Le Grand dictionnaire des cooccurrences*](http://www.guerin-editeur.qc.ca/Product.aspx?id=71022), Beauchesne & filles, Éditions Guérin
> • [*Le Grand Druide des cooccurrences*](https://www.editionsdruide.com/livres/le-grand-druide-des-cooccurrences), Charest, Fontaine & Saint-Germain, Éditions Druide

A [free online version](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/cooc/index-fra.html?lang=fra) of the first title is also available on the French site of the Translation Bureau of the Government of Canada.

---

#### Update

I was in a bookstore yesterday and had a look at the two books mentioned above. *Le Grand Druide* contains **a lot** more data than the other. I also noticed there is a smaller version called [*Le Petit Druide des cooccurrences*](https://www.editionsdruide.com/livres/le-petit-druide-des-cooccurrences), less expensive, but containing only 260,000 collocations vs. the 450,000 of its big brother. Unfortunately, the copies of the smaller one were sealed, so I couldn’t look it up to give my impressions on it here.

It could possible be a good place to start for someone starting to learn French, though.