# How is this linguistic concept called in French?

Tags: expressions, choix-de-mot, linguistique

While studying Russian, I came across the concept of "Coчeтaeмocть", which can be translated as:

(source: [www.textologia.ru/slovari/lingvisticheskie-terminy/sochetaemost/](http://www.textologia.ru/slovari/lingvisticheskie-terminy/sochetaemost/), translation by Google)

> Coincidence is the ability of language elements to connect with each
> other in speech. The combination of the layer. Syntactic composition.

There is even a Wiki-page for it, but it is only available in Russian: [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Сочетаемость](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C)

The idea of this concept is that a word is most often used in a predefined combination with other words. Other combinations are rare or perceived as unnatural w.r.t. commonly used language. I don't have a good example of this in French at the moment, but I'll update the question as soon as I find one.

How is this concept called in French (or English)?

I have been searching, but so far I did not find a name for this concept in another language, although it seems to me that it is an essential mechanism of any language. For the Russian language, I found several exercise books on this topic that have helped me a lot to understand the language better and to construct proper sentences. So I am looking for the name of this concept to find corresponding material in French.

Comment: See also https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/28197/french-collocation-in-use-book ; https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/31847/traduction-du-terme-grammatical-anglais-collocation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The matching term in French is *collocation*.

See here:
https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collocation_(linguistique)

Answer (score 2):

It is called "collocation" in French and in English as well.

From the *[Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/collocation)*

> collocation \kɔ.lɔ.ka.sjɔ̃\ féminin
> (Linguistique) Combinaison de mots caractéristiques, association fréquente de deux mots l’un à l’autre, de manière privilégiée.
>
> Le style journalistique a utilisé des collocations qui sont presque devenues des clichés, comme « crime odieux » ou « lourd silence ».

From *Wikipedia*:
[collocation, linguistique](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collocation_(linguistique))

From [Glosbe](https://fr.glosbe.com/ru/fr/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) : *groupe de mots, collocation*

Answer (score 2):

Il s'agit d'une fonction [*combinatoire*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/combinatoire) d'une unité linguistique. On pourrait parler de *combinabilité*, de capacité d'être *regroupé*, combiné ; donc *combinable*. La *collocation* est assurément un résultat appliqué de cette capacité. On trouvait des indices de ce genre de terminologie dans la [section traduction](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C#%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4) en langue russe pour le terme recherché. Une personne avec une expertise en linguistique est requise pour valider ce qui [se dit](https://cel.archives-ouvertes.fr/halshs-00067979v3/document) dans le domaine, ainsi que l'ensemble des réponses.